# Download offline ElasticSearch documentation for older versions

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I download the user docs/documentation/manual for older ElasticSearch for offline usage?

Recently, the online documentation for older versions of ElasticSearch (for example, [ElasticSearch 1.3.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/getting-started.html)) started to show this message:

> WARNING: Version 1.3 of Elasticsearch has passed its EOL date.
>
> This documentation is no longer being maintained and may be removed. If you are running this version, we strongly advise you to upgrade. For the latest information, see the current release documentation.

What worries me most is the **may be removed** part. Right now, we don't have the resources to upgrade our software to support the latest ElasticSearch version, so we will need to keep working with the older versions for a while. How I will be able to give maintenance to our software if the Elastic company decides to remove the documentation for older versions of ElasticSearch? There is any way to download it from https://www.elastic.co/ or build it from some repository?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the official `elasticsearch` [repository](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) to a local machine, change to branch to the version you want, in your cause branch `1.3`, then you will have the documentation in the directory `docs`.

The documentation is in the `.asciidoc` format, you can try build it following the official [instructions](https://github.com/elastic/docs), or using other asciidoc to pdf/html converters.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to build the HTML version of the docs, but at least the source for the docs are pretty readable by itself!